# I have been facing issues trying to establish client-server connection using Socket.io. Can anyone resolve the issue?

Tags: node.js, express, sockets, websocket, socket.io

Here's the code on which I have been working on.

The client side html code :

```
<body>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
    const socket = io();
</script>
</body>
```

The server.js code :

```
const express = require('express');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = socket(server);

app.use(express.static("public"));

io.on('connection',(sock)=>{
    console.log('CONNECTED');
});


app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

if your code is the exact same in clientside . your are not passing any remote address to your io instance :

```
const socket = io('ws://localhost:3000');
```

Comment: are you using socketio client version?

Comment: I didn't get the question, but I am using `/socket.io/socket.io.js` to expose the client to server

Comment: @MananJoshi are you using this? https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io-client

Comment: Yes, I am using it.

Comment: Thanks dude! Got it... I just had to use `server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000); `